# How to install Drivers of the AMD R9 380 for Debian 9

Tags: debian, drivers, amd

I can't find how to install the drivers of the AMD's r9 380 on Debian 9. And I'm not set up my two monitors. I can only use one.

Answer (score 0):

On AMD [site](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64) are [drivers for Linux](https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/radeon-crimson-15.12-15.302-151217a-297685e.zip) there are packages for Ubuntu, but instructions for manual build too, try it.

> For other distributions, use the following command to determine which parameters you should be using
>   instead. Once the driver package is generated, install it using the package management system for your
>   distribution:
>
> ```
> ./amd***.run --listpkg
> ```

In compability list is *R9 3xx series*.